# SQL Server - How to compare the performance of two triggers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance

I have a trigger created on a table, let's say, TG_A, and now I have optimized this trigger, let's say now, TG_B. Both do the same but TG_B is supposed to be faster than TG_A since I have improved it.

So what I am trying to do is comparing the old trigger, TG_A, with the new one, TG_B in order to ensure that TG_B is faster than TG_A. I want to compare execution times.

How can I do this?

Comment: How about [`sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280646.aspx)?

Comment: This is actually a good question. Assuming I had to do this, I would write a process that activated the trigger, then build it into a loop. On an isolated test server, I would run ... depending, 10k or 100k activations of the old trigger and monitor the overall server load, then do the same for the new trigger. Compare results, flush everything, then run it in reverse - first the new one, then the old one. Compare. Profiler would probably be used in there somewhere as well.

Comment: @LaughingVergil How to monitor the overall server load? Could you explain?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Seems interesting! but how it works? I do not understand at all. For example, I raise the trigger and then I execute the query that is located at the end ot the link you provided. Is it correct? some triggers, one per row, appear. My question is? How long  trigger remains cached? When trigger is removed from the cache? I have observed that after some time elapsed, if I run the query again (the one at the end of the link you provided), nothing is shown.

Comment: @user1624552 - That depends on what tools you currently use to monitor performance (if any). The overall question of monitoring server performance probably has more pages available on the web than the questions related to user '' errors (okay, so I exaggerate a bit). Try [this article](http://www.technig.com/20-best-sql-server-monitoring-tools/), or [this one](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/monitoring-sql-server-important-ever/) for some places to start.

Comment: Triggers can be evicted from cache just like any other query or object - under memory pressure there is an algorithm that determines which plans to evict first based on complexity, frequency, last use, etc.

Comment: @LaughingVergil I am doing what you described in your coments. I have one database with old trigger, and the same database with another name with the new trigger. Now I would like to know how to clear cache before starting the tests. I have tried this before starting each test: USE [MYDB];GO;CHECKPOINT;GO;DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;GO;When test ends on first database,I run this statements and start the same test on another database but it seems cache is not being cleared so is there any effective way to clear cache before performing each test on both databases?

Comment: You should really use the [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) command in this case as well. This pulls pre-compiled SQL out of memory, and allows a clearer comparison.

Comment: Isolate the trigger logic, run and measure the logical reads. Compare

Answer (score 0):

The sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats sounded great. However, be aware that the elapsed time may not give you a good apples to apples comparison between an AFTER and   INSTEAD OF trigger.
The AFTER elapsed times appear to be about 1/3 the time of the INSTEAD OF results, but total duration of the 2 tests is roughly the same with identical behavior. I assume this is because the AFTER results exclude the time for the original insert / update event that caused the trigger to fire, whereas INSTEAD OF elapsed time includes that time.